# How do I disable a jqueryui button

Tags: jquery-ui, button

When I click on a jquery ui button, it still triggers the click event callback. How do I block that event? Do I have to manually keep track of the state or does jquery ui take care of that for me?

Comment: Could you put your code.

Answer (score 38):

Try this.

```
$('#button_id').button("disable");
$('#button_id').button("enable");
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but I still get the .click() callback triggered.

Comment: @ablerman jQueryUI should be handling this correctly for you.  In my local example when I use `$('#button_id').button("disable")` the .click() handler is not triggered for button_id, and then is properly re-enabled when I call `$('#button_id').button('enable')`

Comment: I do this in the click() handler:  ($("#button_id").button().attr("disabled")) return;

Comment: After that button looks like disabled but still works as normal link button.

Answer (score 24):

It works for me:

```
$("#button_id").attr("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

Answer (score 18):

according the documentation:

```
// setter
$( "#button_id" ).button( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Comment: So, exactly you can init your buttons like this: `$( "selector" ).button()
  .click(function ()
  {
   if (this.checked)
    $(this).button("option", "icons", {secondary: "ui-icon-circle-check"})
  })
  .filter(":checked").button({icons: {secondary: "ui-icon-circle-check"}})
  .filter(":disabled").button( "option", "disabled", true );
  });`

Comment: This won't set the ui-state-disabled class, so the button will still look enabled.

Answer (score 3):

If you define like this:

```
$("#mybtn").button();
```

you must enable/disable like this:

```
$("#mybtn").button("enable");
// OR
$("#mybtn").button("disable");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually:

```
$("#btn").button({"disabled":true});
```