# Disable jQuery button - no recipes still

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Browse internet to find how to disable button:

```
<td valign="center" halign="left"><a href="#" id="save-user" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="check">Save</a></td>
```

There were most of recipes with no result:

```
$('#operator-modify').ready( function () {
// None of the below disable button
//$("#save-user").attr("disabled", true).button("refresh");
//$('#save-user').addClass('ui-state-disabled').attr('disabled', true);
//$('#save-user').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass( 'ui-state-disabled');
});
```

Finally - how to enable / disable button?

Comment: try to use the <button> tag instead of the <a> tag http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/yrYyY/1/ click on the button in the fiddle to see it disabled

Comment: You're using an <a> tag. Not a button. If you want to use an <a> tag give it a class such as 'disabled' then if it has that class return false; or preventDefault() or change it to be a <button>

Comment: Based on the `.button()` and `ui-state-disabled`, this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738527/how-do-i-disable-a-jqueryui-button

Comment: Have you tried using the [JQM disable method](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-disable) for example `$('#save-user').button('disable');` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery mobile has several types of buttons. The first one from the "basics" page is `<a data-role="button">`. This type of buttons can be disabled by applying `.ui-disabled` class:

```
$('#operator-modify').ready( function () {
   $('#save-user').addClass('ui-disabled');
});
```

There is a note about links styled as button in [documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/).

> **Note**: Links styled like buttons have all the same visual options as
>   true form-based buttons below, but there are a few important
>   differences. Link-based buttons aren't part of the `button` plugin and
>   only just use the underlying `buttonMarkup` plugin to generate the
>   button styles so the form button methods (enable, disable, refresh)
>   aren't supported. If you need to disable a link-based button (or any
>   element), it's possible to apply the disabled class ui-disabled
>   yourself with JavaScript to achieve the same effect.

Other type of buttons is `<input type="button">` and `<button>`. This type of buttons can be disabled with calling "disable" method of "button" widget.

```
$('#operator-modify').ready( function () {
   $('#save-user').button('disable');
});
```

Complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/xH7W3/3/

Answer (score 4):

When you use a link tag as a [button](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button) (that is adding `data-role="button"`) JQM the buttonMarkup plugin to apply the button widgets markup/styling but does **not** actually create a button widget. Since you don't actaully have a button widget you can't use the button widgets methods (enable, disable etc.), instead to disable or enable your *"button"* you need to add/remove the `ui-disabled` class.

`$('#save-user').addClass("ui-disabled");`

And here is a simple [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/osofez/1/)

As a side note if your not using your button for navigation you might want to use a form button (`input`, `button`), if you do use a regular button then you can instead use the JQM buttons [disable](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-disable) method.

Answer (score 0):

You're not trying to disable a button, but an anchor `<a>` tag.

Either convert to use `<button>` or use an `.click()` to return `false` when it shouldn't go anywhere / do anything.

You might also need to define another style for your anchor when it is "disabled"

I'd recommend using `<button>`, though...

Answer (score 0):

what you have is not a button. It's an html anchor tag. That's the reason why the button related disable features aren't working for you.

If you can change the `<a>` tag to a `<button>` tag or `<input type="button" />` then the following should work.
`$("#save-user").attr("disabled", true);`

If you cant change that to a button, then you can add style class to make the hyperlink look disabled (grey color and mouse cursor normal instead of pointer), and prevent default on click.

Answer (score -1):

You are using an anchor < a> element. Which does not have an attribute like disabled.
To disable an anchor element, you could do the following:

```
$("#save-user").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

the preventDefault makes sure that any HTML / browser reaction will be cancelled.

If you'd simply like to disable a button, which could either be an input < input> element or a < button> element, you could simply do the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" disabled/>
```